# Can't serve vue.js SPA app using the NoRoute function

Tags: vue.js, go, go-gin

I have a project which is establishing a gin-server hosting both the api and a SPA vue.js app in the same docker container:

```
code
├── main.go
├── Routes
│   └── Routes.go
├── Controllers
│   ├── Controllers.go
│   ...
└── web
    ├── src
    │   └── App.vue
    ├── dist
    ├── public
    ...
```

The frontend is working well when its hosted in the developer js server and the api alone also working well but when I host the vue.js app in the gin-server, the backend gin router show my app in regular "/" route but gives me 404 when trying to get to my subroutes managed by th VueRouter. I want to be able to route whatever is not part of the api to the VueRouter, I based my code on a few guides, also tried to tackle it with issues that i found in the product but no luck:

- https://github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/issues/90
- https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/75

this is my Routes.go:

```
package Routes

import (
    "path"
    "strings"
    "devops-portal/Controllers"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gobuffalo/packr/v2"
)

//SetupRouter ... Configure routes
func SetupRouter() *gin.Engine {
    r := gin.Default()
    webFiles := packr.New("web app", "../web/dist")
    r.Use(StaticServe("/", webFiles))

    grp1 := r.Group("/api/v1")
    {
        grp1.GET("request", Controllers.GetRequests)
        grp1.POST("create-request", Controllers.CreateRequest)
        grp1.GET("request/:id", Controllers.GetRequestByID)
        grp1.PUT("request/:id", Controllers.UpdateRequest)
        grp1.DELETE("request/:id", Controllers.DeleteRequest)
    }
    r.NoRoute(func(c *gin.Context){
    c.File("../web/dist/index.html")
    })

    return r
}

func ReturnPublic() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(context *gin.Context) {
        method := context.Request.Method
        if method == "GET" {
            context.File("./public")
        } else {
            context.Next()
        }
    }
}

func exists(fs *packr.Box, prefix string, filepath string) bool {
    if p := strings.TrimPrefix(filepath, prefix); len(p) < len(filepath) {
        name := path.Join("/", p)
        if fs.HasDir(name) {
            index := path.Join(name, "index.html")
            if !fs.Has(index) {
                return false
            }
        } else if !fs.Has(name) {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
    return false
}

// StaticServe serves the web app
func StaticServe(urlPrefix string, fs *packr.Box) gin.HandlerFunc {
    fileserver := http.FileServer(fs)
    if urlPrefix != "" {
        fileserver = http.StripPrefix(urlPrefix, fileserver)
    }
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        if exists(fs, urlPrefix, c.Request.URL.Path) {
            fileserver.ServeHTTP(c.Writer, c.Request)
            c.Abort()
        }
    }
}
```

VueRouter - web/src/router/index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Auth from '@okta/okta-vue'

Vue.use(Auth, {
  issuer: 'https://xxxxx.okta.com/',
  client_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/implicit/callback',
  scope: 'openid profile email',
  pkce: true
})

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: () => import('../views/Login.vue')},
    { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: () => import('../views/requests.vue'), meta: { requiresAuth: true }},
    { path: '/requests', name: 'Requests', component: () => import('../views/requests.vue'), meta: { requiresAuth: true }},
    { path: '/implicit/callback', component: Auth.handleCallback() }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

router.beforeEach(Vue.prototype.$auth.authRedirectGuard());

export default router
```

As you can I configured authentication with OKTA, the problem is when the OKTA servers is redirecting to the callback url which is /implicit/callback... It just gives 404 instead of serving the vue route.

Comment: Can you post the vue js router as well?

Comment: Added the VueRouter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone experiencing this issue i was able to solve my problem by removing all the middleware i copied from the issues and simply use the gin-static middleware:

```
r := gin.Default()

r.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("./web/dist", true)))
grp1 := r.Group("/api/v1")
{
    grp1.GET("request", Controllers.GetRequests)
    grp1.POST("create-request", Controllers.CreateRequest)
    grp1.GET("request/:id", Controllers.GetRequestByID)
    grp1.PUT("request/:id", Controllers.UpdateRequest)
    grp1.DELETE("request/:id", Controllers.DeleteRequest)
}
r.NoRoute(func(c *gin.Context){
    c.File("./web/dist/index.html")
})
```